# Adding specific headers depending on file names

Tags: bash, shell

I have some text files with the following names:

```
testfile_1_from_Country_A_final.txt
testfile_2_from_Country_A_final.txt

testfile_1_from_Country_B_final.txt
testfile_2_from_Country_B_final.txt

testfile_1_from_Country_C_final.txt
testfile_2_from_Country_C_final.txt
```

and I have to add a specific header which consist of three numbers to every file depending on the number of the test file (for example testfile_1) and the name of the Country (for example Country A) and a "1" regardless of the test file or country name.

For instance, if the data from test file_1_from_Country_A_final.txt is this:

```
blablablabalabalbalablabbla
blabalalbblalbablablalbabla
blalalbablalblabblalbalbalb
blabalbalblbalbalbalbalbalb
abllablbalbalbalbalbalbalba
```

the new file should look like this:

```
30 7 1
blablablabalabalbalablabbla
blabalalbblalbablablalbabla
blalalbablalblabblalbalbalb
blabalbalblbalbalbalbalbalb
abllablbalbalbalbalbalbalba
```

30 because it was the country A and the 7 because it was test_file number 1 and the final 1 is a must for every file.

**EXTRA INFO**

Actually there a lots of files for lots of countries so maybe it will be a good idea to have separate text files with the numbers for each test_file numbers and the number for each country that is needed to be added to the header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain A → 30 and 1 → 7.

Comment: Have you tried to accomplish what you've described? Did you have difficulty with anything in particular?
It sounds like you want a bash script that breaks the filename into its pieces delimited by underscores, selects the number that corresponds to the country-name piece, and prints the numbers followed by the file contents. Are we meant to understand that the filename is a command-line argument to the script?

Comment: @Alfe : For Countries A to Z I have a list with different numbers, and from files 1 to 22 from each country I have another list with different numbers. So depending on every test file name of each country is a different header combination that should be added to each particular file.

Comment: How is this list provided?  Is it in a file?  What format?

Comment: @minopret: Yes, I am trying to use a if command using -f to see if the file has a particular name and then trying to echo something to a file that should be the starting line of the header but I am having problems with that. I will uploaded as soon as I get it to run. And sorry but I do not understand your question about the filenames and command-line arguments.

Comment: @Alfe I just name a 2 column file with numbers 1-22 (numbers of test file) which the number that should be added.

Comment: So, you have two conversion files, one describing how the country letter is converted and one describing how the number is converted?  Please give an example line for each of these files.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to split the file name, convert the elements and insert a header line into the file:

```
for fileName in testfile*.txt
do
  if [[ "$fileName" =~ testfile_([0-9]+)_from_Country_([A-Za-z_]+)_final.txt ]]
  then
    number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    country=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

    # now convert the number and the country
    convertedNumber=$(grep "^$number " numberConversionFile.txt | cut -d' ' -f2)
    convertedCountry=$(grep "^$country " countryConversionFile.txt | cut -d' ' -f2)

    sed -i "1i$convertedCountry $convertedNumber 1" "$fileName"
  fi
done
```

Comment: I added a `case` statement for conversion of letters/numbers.  Depending on how that list of conversions is provided, there probably are smarter solutions than just listing all combinations.

Comment: I removed the stupid `case` logic again and added instead a part which assumes that there are two conversion files, each containing lines like `A 30` and `1 7` for the given example.

Comment: Hi Alfie sorry for this new inconvenience but actually the Country_A given as example was something like Cape_Verde, The_Bahamas, and some without the _ for example, just Peru. How should I change the if statement? Like this?? : testfile_([0-9]+)_from_([A-Z,a-z,_])_final.txt ???.

Comment: I adopted the regexp used above to also match things like `Cape_Verde` and `Peru`.  And since this isn't a letter anymore, I also changed the name to `country` throughout ;-)

Comment: I now assume the `countryConversionFile.txt` has lines like `Cape_Verde 30` and `Peru 31`.

Comment: Thanks again. I had a warning/error message in the prompt sed: -i may not be used with stdin. What does that mean?

Comment: It means that you did not apply my code properly.  If you use `sed` with `-i` it means that the given file shall be changed _inplace_ (instead of reading and writing from stdin/stdout).  You obviously haven't given a file name, though, so `sed` defaults to reading stdin.  My code, however, gives `"$fileName"` as file name.  I guess you just mistyped something, forgot quotes, etc.

Comment: Copy & Paste your `sed`-line in a comment here (don't type it again, use copy & paste!), then I can say more about that error.

Comment: sed -i "1i$convertedCountry $convertedNumber 1" "$fileName"

Comment: Strange.  You also have sth like `for fileName in testfile*.txt` to fill the variable?

Comment: You could add an `echo` before the `sed` command:  `echo sed -i "1i...` and tell me what this gives out.

Comment: I got this message now: 
sed -i 1i  1 reduced_filt_MAF_b37_chr9_Tunisia_ldhat.txt

Comment: Maybe a did something wrong in the for statement this is the one that I used and this is an example of my file:

for fileName in reduced_filt_MAF_b37_chr*.txt 

and this are my name files

reduced_filt_MAF_b37_chr10_Algeria_ldhat.txt
reduced_filt_MAF_b37_chr10_Morocco_N_ldhat.txt

Comment: I did an echo on $convertedNumber and $convertedCountry and I got nothing... I guess something was wrong with that? Also, was I supposed to change something in number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} and country=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}??

Comment: This is all very strange.  Can you paste you complete code to pastebin or sth similar?  Maybe I can see what's going wrong.

Comment: What I can already say is: The conversion of the values fails.  Have a look at your conversion files and what the `grep`s return (add `echo`s for this in your script).  I've checked your code and have no problems to make it run without error.  See http://pastebin.com/EWtVcP9y for my test run.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with using grep s and adding echo s in my script.

Comment: This is too deep now, sorry.  But I'm sure if you ask another official question like "Why is this `grep` not working as expected?" and "How can I debug this `grep` using debug output with `echo`?", then lots of users would be happy to help you out here :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alfe, we were almost there :(

Comment: Don't give up, though :)  Ask more questions, I'm sure your current problems can be solved as well.  Refer to this question here if you like.  It will ease understanding, but paste the current code again in the new question and ask how to debug the problems with the `grep` which doesn't seem to function as expected in your environment.

Comment: But I must admit that I'm clueless how you can get that error message by the `sed` program.  The only explanation I have is that you execute something different (maybe an older version, forgotten to press save button or similar) than the code we talk about.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps involved here. Firstly, you need to iterate over the files. This can be done using a for-loop:

```
for filename in testfile_*.txt
do
   ...
done
```

Then, you need to extract the test file number and country from each filename. This can be done by splitting the filename on `_` as shown below:

```
IFS=_ read -a arr <<< "$filename"
test_file_num="${arr[1]}"
country="${arr[4]}"
```

Next, you need to convert the test file number and country into numbers. You haven't provided information on how, for example, country A becomes the number 30.

Finally you need to write the header to each file. This can be done using a temporary file like this:

```
echo "30 7 1" > tmpfile
cat "$filename" >> tmpfile
mv tmpfile "$filename"
```